# Adding ID_number to XML

Tags: python, xml

I have problem with adding unique ID to XML. With this solution I further work in SQL, I need some unique number.

I write some code in py but doesnt work.

```
tree = ET.parse('country.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

for L in root.iter ('country/gps1/gps2/L'):
    new_L = int(L.text) + 1
    L.set(new_L)
tree.write('output.xml')
```

Here is XML:

```
<data>
  <country name="Liechtenstein">
    <rank>1</rank>
    <gps1>
      <gps2>    
        <L>
          <B S="sdafasfsda"/>
          <B S="sdafasfssda"/>          
        </L>
        <L>
          <B S="sqdafasfsda"/>
          <B S="sqdafasfssda"/>
          <B S="sdafasdfsda"/>          
        </L>
        <L>
          <B S="sdafaxsfsda"/>
          <B S="sdafaxsfssda"/>
          <B S="sdafaxsdfsda"/>         
        </L>
      </gps2>
    </gps1>
    <year>2008</year>
    <gdppc>141100</gdppc>
    <neighbor name="Austria" direction="E"/>
    <neighbor name="Switzerland" direction="W"/>
  </country>
  <country name="Singapore">
    <rank>4</rank>
    <gps1> 
      <gps2>  
        <L>
          <B S="sdafasfsd2a"/>
          <B S="sdafasfssd2a"/>
          <B S="sdafasdfsda2"/>         
        </L>
      </gps2>
    </gps1>
    <year>2011</year>
    <gdppc>59900</gdppc>
    <neighbor name="Malaysia" direction="N"/>
  </country>
  <country name="Panama">
    <rank>68</rank>
    <year>2011</year>
    <gdppc>13600</gdppc>
    <neighbor name="Costa Rica" direction="W"/>
    <neighbor name="Colombia" direction="E"/>
  </country>
</data>
```

I except adding unique number on tag 'L'. Should be enough when will be number 1,2,3,4,5,6... (i++). For example I demonstrate the result:

```
...
<gps1>
      <gps2>    
        <L ID=1>
          <B S="sdafasfsda"/>
          <B S="sdafasfssda"/>          
        </L>
        <L ID=2>
          <B S="sqdafasfsda"/>
          <B S="sqdafasfssda"/>
          <B S="sdafasdfsda"/>          
        </L>
        <L ID=3>
          <B S="sdafaxsfsda"/>
          <B S="sdafaxsfssda"/>
          <B S="sdafaxsdfsda"/>         
        </L>
      </gps2>
</gps1>
...
```

Thanks

Comment: I add that I work with xml file -> country.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you can add an `ID` attribute with a unique value to every `L` element:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse('country.xml')

id_no = 1

for L in tree.iter('L'):     
    L.set('ID', str(id_no))  
    id_no += 1

tree.write('output.xml')
```